# CSS3: transform - не затрагивая текст

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Как можно с помощью CSS или JS сделать transform не трогая текст?

Как сейчас:

```
            &:hover
            transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(-12deg) translate(0px)
            background: #fff
            text-decoration: none
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если не затрагивая текст, то с помощью псевдоэлементов :before или :after

[пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/LZNNXO?editors=1100)

```
&:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(-12deg) translate(0px);
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 5;        
        opacity: 0;
      }
```

Comment: мда уж, препроцессоры еще то извращение))

Comment: В codepen есть возможность увидеть скомпилированный код выбрав  "view compiled" )

Comment: да, я в курсе, я вообще про эту херь))

Answer (score 2):

C помощю jquery:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".item").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css({
        transform: "rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(-12deg) translate(0px)",
        background: "#fff"
      })
      $(this).children('p').css({
        transform: "rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(12deg) translate(0px)"
      })
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css({
        transform: "rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(0deg) translate(0px)",
        background: "none"
      })
      $(this).children('p').css({
        transform: "rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(0deg) translate(0px)"
      })
    }
  )
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #fcc01f;
  list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="item">
    <p>text 1</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>text 2</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>text 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: хм, присмотрелся, я похоже сделал ваш вариант, только на `css` :) объясните, зачем вы для  `hover` используете  `jquery`?

Comment: Просто мне так проще плюс не надо плодить кучу классов html код выглядет чище.

Comment: Вам проще написать 20 строк на JS вместо 2 на css? а представьте что у вас в проекте сотни строк JS, а вы ещё и на каждый hover функцию вешаете :)

Comment: я же не сказал что я исключительно JS пользуюсь. В данном конкретном случае для меня проще было это сделать на JS. Хотя если подумать то можно и вовсе без него обойтись.

Comment: Добавил еще один ответ. Да и к стати у вас css кода тоже много строчек ))

Answer (score 1):

Можно так сделать, добавить тексту обратный `skew`, чтобы он был ровным. Добавил немного jquery, но только для того, чтобы можно было понажимать пункты меню в примере.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-item', function() {
    $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #232423;
}
.nav-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fcc01f;
}
.nav-list .nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.nav-list .nav-item.active {
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(-12deg) translate(0px);
  background: #fff;
}
.nav-list .nav-item .nav-link {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #111;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.nav-list .nav-item.active .nav-link {
  transform: skew(12deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-list">
  <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">главная</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">о нас</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">цены</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #fcc01f;
  list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(-12deg) translate(0px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  }
.item p{
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.001) skew(12deg) translate(0px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="item">
    <p>text 1</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>text 2</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <p>text 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```